# Asp.Net MVC3 Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action like shown below. In GetAvailableBookList, I get the list and if there is not any available book redirect to a message page. But in action part code continues to execute and gets an exception and I find myself in error page. 
*I don't want to use return RedirectToAction or something like that* because there are a lot of places where we use this redirect logic in our application.

```
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        List<BookType> bookList = GetAvailableBookList();
        // some code
        return View("RelatedView");
    }

    private List<BookType> GetAvailableBookList()
    {
        ....
        list  = GetList();
        if(list.Count == 0)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(messagePageUrl, true);
        }
        else return list;
    }
```

Comment: My opinion would be that you do not do a redirect at the GetAvailableBookList() level but rather at the ActionResult ActionName() level. Since GetAvailableBookList() gets called from various areas as you have mentioned.

Comment: Then I will repeat Redirect in each Action that I do not want to do. It is a specific example. In business part we do this redirect several times for several purposes. For example, while getting a list I may want to check the time if user can see this list now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Response.Redirect()` isn't really friendly with ASP.NET MVC.  My rule of thumb is if it comes from HttpContext I don't want to touch it in the controller (of course there are many exceptions to that rule) -- especially since it improves testability.

My suggestion *is* to use `RedirectToAction`, but since you don't want to repeat code you can do it in such a way that you don't have to repeat code (although in this case I don't see a problem with repeating code).

```
public ActionResult LoadBookListAndContinue(
  Func<List<BookType>, ActionResult> continuation)
{
   var list = LoadBooklist();
   if(list.Any())
   {
     return action(continuation); 
   }
   return new RedirectResult(messagePageUrl);
}


// in your controller
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
  return LoadBookListAndContinue(
    list => {
      // some code
      return View("RelatedView");
    });
}
```

Is it pretty?  No, but it works better than the Redirect exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return RedirectToAction("NoListAvailable");
```

if you have a specific action you would like to execute. The NoListAvailable action can return a view indicating the problem.

Alternatively, you could return the view directly

```
return View("NoListAvailable");
```

Comment: He said he didn't want to do that.

Comment: I don't want to return anything as I stated in the question, I just want to do a classical redirect.

Comment: I don't honestly see the difference between RedirectToAction and a classical Redirect. One keeps with the MVC pattern and the other breaks it. Do you really need a Response.Redirect()?

Comment: In an action, you have to return something. I want to break the action flow without return something.

Comment: An action just has to return a view. When you use a Redirect() you are pointing the browser to another resource, typically a HTML page, which is what a View is. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could throw an Exception and have the Error handler return a typical error page?

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is probably ThreadAbortException and this is something you cannot avoid unless you allow the thread to continue (2nd argument in Response.Redirect).

On a side note your current solution is generally flawed. You should use RedirectToAction in each action when your method returns an empty list.

Comment: The exception is because in the code for example I use something like that: list[0] and since list is null I get exception

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a specific exception and redirect where you catch it may be solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(messagePageUrl, false);
```